# DialogInterface.onClickListener causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, onclick, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting the exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to build a `DialogInterface.onClickListener` that I use in an Activity when pressing an menu item.

this is the code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener yesHandler =
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            finish();
        }
    };
}
```

When I press the menu item, that above code is invoked and the app crashes with this stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.syncpro.SyncMainActivity$1
at com.syncpro.SyncMainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(SyncMainActivity.java:120)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:774)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Force finishing activity com.syncpro/.SyncMainActivity
```

The error code line is `SyncMainActivity.java:120` is exactly that one I pasted above (i.e. the creation of `onClickListener`).
I'm using API level 7.
Any idea about the cause and solution ?

Comment: where is the AlertDialog where you want to add the Listener?

Comment: in that line no 120 what you are doing ? which is that line ?

Comment: @Lalit;
sorry for my innacuracy; more code here: [link] (http://pastebin.com/hNFwRTc8)

The crash occurs already at the first OnClickListener creation.

Comment: @Karthick: this is the line 120:

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener yesHandler = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...

Comment: @user1131951 you should look at the examples on net there are many already for AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.syncpro.SyncMainActivity
```

This is your error, it means that it cannot find your SyncMainActivity class.